# Complex cross-ratio and determinants

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Suppose that $z_1,z_2,z_3,$ and $w_1,w_2,w_3$ are two triplets of complex numbers. Show that if $w = T(z)$ is the Möbius transformation such that $T(z_j) = w_j$ for $j = 1,2,3$ then it can be described by the equation:

$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
        1&1&1&1\\
        z&z_1&z_2&z_3\\
        w&w_1&w_2&w_3\\
        zw&z_1w_1&z_2w_2&z_3w_3\\
\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$

I dont understand where the determinant comes from. I am assuming (since we are dealing with triplets of points) that we are supposed to use the cross-ratio, but I have never seen a determinant used together with cross-ratio in complex analysis. Any pointers on how to approach a problem like this? What theory am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the determinant along the first column to see that the equation is of the form
$$
 A + Bz + Cw + Dzw = 0 \iff w = \frac{-A-Bz}{C+Dz} =: S(z)
$$
for some complex constants $A, B, C, D$. So the equation defines a Möbius transformation $S$.  If $(z, w) = (z_j, w_j)$ for some $j$ then the determinant is zero because  two columns of the determinant are equal. It follows that $S(z_j) = w_j$ for $j=1,2,3$, and since Möbius transformations are uniquely determined by their images at three distinct points, $S = T$.